# Shake Icons on Longpress [EDIT MODE]

Tags: android, icons, imagebutton

I have an Android application with some ImageButtons, just like icons.

I would like to know how I could implement a function to "shake" icons after user long-presses them. Like iPhone icons on edit mode, you know?

After editing, icons stop shaking.

Is it possible to do that in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this to start the shaking animation on your icons upon the long press event of your button

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
    findViewById(R.id.pw).startAnimation(shake);
}
```

This snippet is taking from the android API Demo here http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Animation1.html

Answer (score -1):

Try to use TranslateAnimation (And/Or AnimationSet) on the button.

something like this:

```
private void onYourButtonLongPress()
{
    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, -5, 0, 0);
    animation.setDuration(100):
    yourButton.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

notice that this example is only for shake to left